# UI framework for pure actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, user-interface, frameworks

Are there any frameworks/libs for ui development in as3, except Flex?
Just common things like textfields with scrolls, accordion, carousel and so on?

Comment: You could Google that. There are many components. If you want advice tell more about what you need/what you prefer.

Comment: I highly recommend building your own if you are using AS3 and not Flex. I ran into a similar issue about 3 months ago when we abandoned Flex for a project and I was told to rewrite it all in AS3. In the end, GUI frameworks are great but they are always limited and always have their own oddities. If you build your own (as I did), you have full control over those limitations and oddities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are :)

A couple of the better known ones are:

http://www.minimalcomps.com/ - this is very lightweight and easy to use, but skinning options are limited.

http://feathersui.com/ - this utilises Stage3D (ie gpu rendering) so its ideal for mobile apps

Answer (score 0):

Aswing([www.aswing.org](http://www.aswing.org/)) is easiest to use when build UI for web app without Flex, but for Mobile, feathersui(http://feathersui.com/) is the only option. About performance, both are affordable(But not well optimized in my opinion).